# How can I implement a sidebar menu like spotify?

Tags: ios, swift, spotify, sidebar

I want to implement a sidebar menu like Spotify:

[image: Sidebar]

I think it's pretty difficult.

Important features:

- when the sidebar appears, the main view should transit to the left
- sidebar should fill the full screen, not only a part of the screen 
  => This [solution](https://github.com/evnaz/ENSwiftSideMenu) does not cover the the full screen
- menu should be available from every screen except login screen
- close the sidebar by swiping the main screen to the right

=> Same functionality like the spotify app

Could you help me finding the right path to the solution? 
Which controllers do I have to take? 
How should I combine them? 
Do you know well written tutorials?

**Update** 
[Solution Nr. 1](http://code4app.net/ios/iOS-Slide-Menu/5477e063e247411704b03ca0)
=> Try to implement it at the moment!

**Followup Questions**
I don't need the RightMenuView Controller and some other features.
Does it make sense to rewrite the code in Swift?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many tutorials on the net... For example:

http://code4app.net/category/menu

http://www.raywenderlich.com/78568/create-slide-out-navigation-panel-swift

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Comment: I just wanted to help... What would the essential part of this question be? He asked for written tutorials... I´m experiencing the same here, if you are noob, you won´t get helped, only corrected in how to ask "correctly" here...

Comment: You could improve your answer by including some code examples given on the second website, for example. I know it can be rough to start on SO, but part of that is because the overload of questions makes it important that they follow strict rules, which might be difficult to start with. But you'll learn over time, just like anyone did :-) Pointing out what can be improved is a great way to help others start of without downvotes etc. ;-)

Comment: OK I see... I´m starting to understand the "system" here and I gave my first answers with code examples. But seriously, for this question, what would a code example for a whole SideMenuViewController be? Giving a link for a whole tutorial on this, for which he asked for by the way will help him better, isn´t it? In my Opinion my answer is better than no answer...

Comment: Tbh, I haven't read the full question being asked here, and I haven't looked in depth to the urls you posted: So I don't really know if it would be helpful. "Link only" answers most of the time don't really add anything, as the websites might be removed etc. Anyway, I looked at your other answers and they looked alright ;)

Comment: Where is the like button? ;)

Comment: Thanks, your links are awesome! I have already found the second one, but the first one was really helpful. This http://code4app.net/ios/iOS-Slide-Menu/5477e063e247411704b03ca0 seems to be the menu I'm looking for. If I have some implementing issues could I go one asking in this thread?